# Why is my input freezing?

Tags: c

I wrote this C code for Conway's Game of Life simulation. It works perfectly except for when user enter a character as input.This is what I've done so far. If I enter any character e.g. * or / when the program asks for input, the program freezes or goes in a infinite loop. Can someone help me about it. I've tweaked the code in all possible ways to remove the bug but all in vain.

```
#include "stdio.h" //for all basic functions
#include "stdlib.h"//for exit function
#include "time.h" //for random seed
#include "windows.h" //for Sleep function
#include "conio.h" //for _kbhit function
#define scanf_s scanf //typing scanf_s is tedious compared to typing scanf

void neighbour_manager();//custom function to calculate neighbours and make a cell alive or dead accordingly
void generation_printer();//custom function to print the generations after selecting seed type

//initializing all variables
int generation;
char fill_char;
char array[35][85];
char array1[35][85];
char live = '+';//using + sign for live cells
char dead = ' ';//using blank spaces for dead cells
char n;
char random_seed[3]={' ','+','\0'};//for random seed i.e. (case:12)
//SEEDS
char block[2][2] = {{'+','+'}, {'+','+'}};
char boat[3][3] = {{'+','+',' '}, {'+',' ','+'}, {' ','+',' '}};
char loaf[4][4] = {{' ','+','+',' '},{'+', ' ', ' ', '+'},{' ', '+', ' ', '+'},{' ', ' ', '+', ' '}};
char beehive[3][4] = {{' ','+','+',' '},{'+', ' ', ' ', '+'},{' ', '+', '+', ' '}};
char blinker[1][3] = {{'+', '+','+'}};
char beacon[4][4] = {{'+','+',' ',' '},{'+',' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' ','+'},{' ',' ','+','+'}};
char toad[2][4] = {{' ','+','+','+'},{'+','+','+',' '}};
char pulsar[15][15] = {
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {'+','+','+',' ',' ','+','+',' ','+','+',' ',' ','+','+','+'},
                           {' ',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ',' '},
                           {'+','+','+',' ',' ','+','+',' ','+','+',' ',' ','+','+','+'},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' '}
                          };
char glider[3][3] = {{' ','+',' '},{' ',' ','+'},{'+','+','+'}};
char spaceship[4][5] = {{'+',' ',' ','+',' '},{' ',' ',' ',' ','+'},{'+',' ',' ',' ','+'},{' ','+','+','+','+',}};
char gosper_glider_gun[15][38] = {
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', '+', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', '+', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', '+', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', '+', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }
                                 };


//main function starts here
int main(void)
{int i = 0, j = 0;                  //initializing some more variables
    int a = 0, b = 0, seed_type = 0;
    int choice_after_execution=0;
    system("title CONWAY'S GAME OF LIFE");//to change the console title
    _flushall();//to remove garbage values
    printf("\t\t\t\t\tWelcome to Conway's Game of Life\n");//welcome note
    Sleep(2500);//for dramatic purposes
    system("cls");
    printf("Please make sure the console is maximized for optimal simulation.");//whole grid is not visible if console is not maximized
    Sleep(2000);//to create a pause to maximize screen before proceeding

    start:                         //jump point in case user decides to restart the game
    for (i = 0; i < 35; i++) {     //emptying the array to avoid double printing of patterns in the same grid
        for (j = 0; j < 85; j++) {
            array[i][j]=dead;
        }
    }
    system("cls");

    printf("Select the seed type\nSTILL LIFE PATTERNS\nEnter 1 for Block \nEnter 2 for Loaf \nEnter 3 for Boat\nEnter 4 for Beehive\n\nOSCILLATORS\nEnter 5 for Blinker\nEnter 6 for Beacon\nEnter 7 for Toad\nEnter 8 for Pulsar\n\nGLIDERS AND SPACSHIPS\nEnter 9 for Glider\nEnter 10 for Spaceship\n\nGOSPER GLIDER GUN\nEnter 11 for Gosper Glider Gun\n\nRANDOM\nEnter 12 for Random\n\nYour choice: ");
    retake_seed_type: //jump point for invalid choice

            scanf("%d", &seed_type);

    srand(time(NULL)); //random seed generator
    a = 1 + rand() % 35; //randomizing the row for first generation
    b = 1 + rand() % 85; //randomizing the column for first generation


    switch (seed_type)//switch case for different seed types
    {
    case 1: //for block
        for (i = a; i < a + 2; i++){
            for (j = b; j < b + 2; j++){

                array[i%35][j%85] = block[i - a][j - b];//i%35 and j%85 to facilitate wrap around
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2://for loaf
        for (i = a; i <a + 4; i++){
            for (j = b; j <b + 4; j++){
                array[i%35][j%85] = loaf[i - a][j - b];//i%35 and j%85 to facilitate wrap around
            }
        }
        break;
    case 3://for boat
        for (i = a; i <a + 3; i++){
            for (j = b; j <b + 3; j++){

                array[i%35][j%85] = boat[i - a][j - b];//i%35 and j%85 to facilitate wrap around
            }
        }
        break;
    case 4://beehive
        for(i = a; i <a + 3; i++){
          for(j = b; j <b + 4; j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = beehive[i-a][j-b];//i%35 and j%85 to facilitate wrap around
          }
        }
        break;
    case 5://blinker
        for(i=a;i<a+1;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+3;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = blinker[i-a][j-b];//i%35 and j%85 to facilitate wrap around
          }
        }
        break;
    case 6://beacon
        for(i=a;i<a+4;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+4;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = beacon[i-a][j-b];//i%35 and j%85 to facilitate wrap around
          }
        }
        break;
    case 7://Toad
        for(i=a;i<a+2;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+4;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = toad[i-a][j-b];//i%35 and j%85 to facilitate wrap around
          }
        }
        break;
    case 8://Pulsar
        for(i=a;i<a+15;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+15;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = pulsar[i-a][j-b];//i%35 and j%85 to facilitate wrap around
          }
        }
        break;
        case 9://glider
        for(i=a;i<a+3;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+3;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = glider[i-a][j-b];//i%35 and j%85 to facilitate wrap around
          }
        }
        break;
        case 10://spaceship
        for(i=a;i<a+4;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+5;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = spaceship[i-a][j-b];//i%35 and j%85 to facilitate wrap around
          }
        }
        break;
        case 11://gosper glider gun
        for(i=a;i<a+15;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+38;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = gosper_glider_gun[i-a][j-b];//i%35 and j%85 to facilitate wrap around
          }
        }
        break;
        case 12://random
           a=0;
           b=0;
            for(i=a;i<35;i++){
                for(j=b;j<85;j++){
                array[i][j] = random_seed[1+rand()%2];
          }
        }
        break;

    default://default case asks for input again
            printf("Enter a valid choice i.e. from 1 to 12: ");
            goto retake_seed_type;//go-to statement to take seed_type input again
    }
    printf("\nEnter the number of generations(-1 for infinite): ");
    scanf_s("%d", &generation);
if(generation>0){//different cases for generation input
    for (i = 1; i <= generation; i++){
        system("cls");
        neighbour_manager();
        generation_printer();
        printf("GENERATION NUMBER: %d\n", i);//to know how many generations have been printed
        printf("Press any key to stop simulation.\n");
        if(_kbhit())//if user presses a key to stop simulation
            {
            printf("Generation Interrupted.");
        break;
        }
        if(i==generation)//if user does not interrupt generations
        {
            Sleep(200);//dramatic purposes
            printf("Generation completed successfully.");
        }

        Sleep(700);//according to the instructions
    }
}
    if (generation <0)
    {int z=0;
        while (!_kbhit())//to make sure loop continues printing unless user press a key on keyboard
            {
            system("cls");
            neighbour_manager();
            generation_printer();
            z++;//generation counter
            printf("GENERATION NUMBER: %d\n", z);//to know how many generations have been printed
            printf("Press any key to stop simulation.\n");
            Sleep(700);//according to the instructions
            if(_kbhit())//if user presses a key to stop simulation
            {
            printf("Generation Interrupted.");
        break;
        }

            }

    }
    if(generation==0)
        {   system("cls");
            printf("No generations printed.");
        }

   printf("\nPress 1 to Restart.\nPress 2 to Exit.\nYour Choice: ");//exit message
   after_generation_valid_choice://jump point in case of wrong input choice
   scanf("%d",&choice_after_execution);

   if(choice_after_execution==1)
        goto start;//if user wants to start simulation again then go back to start

   if(choice_after_execution==2)//if user wants to exit
        {
            printf("Thank you for using this program.");
            Sleep(2000);//for dramatic purposes
            goto exit;//if user decides to exit the program then skip system pause and just exit
        }
   else
    {
        printf("Enter a valid choice: ");//if invalid choice is entered ask again
        goto after_generation_valid_choice;
    }

    exit://jump point in case user wants to exit
    exit(0);
}//main end

void neighbour_manager(){                       //custom function to decide whether cells should be alive or dead
    int i, j;                                   //corresponding to the number of neighbours alive or dead
    int neighbour;
    for ( i = 0; i < 35; i++){
        for ( j = 0; j < 85; j++){

            neighbour = 0;
            if (array[i - 1 < 0 ? 34 : i - 1][j - 1 < 0 ? 84 : j - 1] == live)   neighbour = neighbour + 1;//modifications in row and
            if (array[i - 1 < 0 ? 34 : i - 1][j] == live)    neighbour = neighbour + 1;                    //column numbers to ensure
            if (array[i - 1 < 0 ? 34 : i - 1][(j + 1) % 85] == live)    neighbour = neighbour + 1;         //that the patterns wrap
            if (array[i][j - 1 < 0 ? 84 : j - 1] == live)     neighbour = neighbour + 1;                   //around
            if (array[i][(j + 1) % 85] == live)     neighbour = neighbour + 1;
            if (array[(i + 1) % 35][j - 1 < 0 ? 84 : j - 1] == live) neighbour = neighbour + 1;
            if (array[(i + 1) % 35][j] == live) neighbour = neighbour + 1;
            if (array[(i + 1) % 35][(j + 1) % 85] == live) neighbour = neighbour + 1;


            if(neighbour == 3)                        //game rules that decide whether a cell would be alive or
            {                                         //not in the next generation
                array1[i][j] = live;
            }
            else if (neighbour < 2 || neighbour > 3)
            {
                array1[i][j] = dead;
            }
            else
            {
                array1[i][j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<35; i++){                          //replace array1 with array
        for(j=0; j<85; j++){
            array[i][j] = array1[i][j];
            array1[i][j] = ' ';                   // now empty array1
        }
    }
    return;
}


int ran_out_of_variable_names1 = 35;
int ran_out_of_variable_names2 = 85;

void generation_printer() //custom function that prints both border and the array(with patterns)
{
    int i,j;
    // Top border
    for (i = 0; i < ran_out_of_variable_names2 + 2; i++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ran_out_of_variable_names1; i++) {
        // Star to the beginning of the line
        printf("*");
        // Contents of the line
        for (j = 0; j < ran_out_of_variable_names2; j++) {
            printf("%c", array[i][j]);
        }
        // Star at the end of the line
        printf("*\n");
    }
    // Bottom border
    for (i = 0; i < ran_out_of_variable_names2+ 2; i++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
//END OF CODE
```

Comment: `_kbhit` and `goto` is not going to be a problem.

Comment: If the only problem is entering a character as input, you might try to restrict your question to just that and not post your entire code.  First thing anyone has to do to answer your question is find where amongst all that code the input is accepted, and also to figure out what input should be accepted - you have failed to tell us what valid input looks like.  What can the user enter if not a "character"?  All input is characters.

Comment: `scanf` will not clear the input when it can't convert it, the input remains in the buffer. You have to do that yourself. Always check the return value from `scanf` (number of items converted). Better to use `fgets` and then `sscanf`. When it fails, you can dump that string and input another.

Comment: It seems also that your question is about accepting and validating input.  Tagging it [conways-game-of-life] serves no relevant purpose whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

If the input buffer contains non-digit characters and you use `scanf()` rith `%d` to read input, the input will fail and the non-digit characters will remain buffered, only for the subsequent `scanf()` to fail because nothing has changed.

Solutions are legion; here's one:

```
while( scanf("%d",&choice_after_execution) != 1 )
{
    while( getchar() != '\n' ) ; // read buffer until end of line
}
```

An alternative is to read an entire line of input using `fgets()` and parse it using `sscanf()`.

I strongly suggest that however you do it, you wrap the solution in a function for reuse (so you only have to solve the problem once):

```
int getDecimalInput()
{
    int input = 0 ;
    while( scanf("%d",&input) != 1 )
    {
        while( getchar() != '\n' ) ; // read buffer until end of line
    }

    return input ;
}
```